# Return results from database in editable html text form with php

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
EMP    |T_IN    |T_OUT    |ITEM    |NOTES
-----------------------------------------
Name 1 | time   | time    | break  | job1
Name 2 | time   | time    | break  | job2
Name 1 | time   | time    | office | 
Name 3 | time   | time    | fab    | job6
```

The above I need each item in each row column intersection to be displayed in an editable html textbox form for submission to the next step. Ive tried several things... all of which I have abandoned.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="test.php" method="post">
Pay Range 
  <input type="date" name="start">
<input type="date" name="stop">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>


<?php
if($_POST){
mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'Pass');
mysql_select_db('database');
$rt = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM TIME WHERE STAMP BETWEEN '". $_POST['start']."' AND '".$_POST['stop']."'");



while($data = mysql_fetch_array($rt)){

    $results .= $data['EMP'].", ".$data['T_IN'].", ".$_POST['T_OUT'].", ".$_POST['ITEM'].", ".$_POST['NOTE'];
echo $results."<br/>";
}
}




?>
```

UPDATED CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="test.php" method="post">
Pay Range 
  <input type="date" name="start">
<input type="date" name="stop">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>

<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "Pass";
$dbname = "DB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM TIME WHERE STAMP BETWEEN '". $_POST['start']."' AND '".$_POST['stop']."'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "<input type="text" value=\"" . $row['EMP']. "\"> <br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Please Provide some code of what you have already done

Comment: @TomasK Ive deleted it all. But I ran it through a loop and tried several combinations... none of which worked.

Comment: @TomasK though, it may be my crummy scripting.

Comment: Have you tried modifying code of answers like http://stackoverflow.com/q/13549605/4229630 ?

Comment: @TomasK Ive added my code

Comment: So you want to insert code into the database from the inputs?

Comment: @TomasK No. I need it to pull the info from the db then Im going to generate a file for  download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will output all data from your MySql query

```
    <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "myDB";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);?>
      <form action="test.php" method="post">
   <?php if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo '<input type="text" name="myinput" value="' . $row["id"]. '"> <br>'
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    $conn->close();
    ?>
       </form>
```

Snippet & more information at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp)

Comment: How do I place that information into text boxes so it can be edited and the changes submitted?

Comment: Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Comment: I found the problem `'text' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in your code on line 20
echo "<input type="text" value=\"" . $row['EMP']. "\"> <br>";`

Comment: I used `\ to exit the "`

Comment: if you will fix it arround `type=\"text\"` Ill give you the points :)